# hdf5 over ssh in Python

Tags: python, ssh, hdf5, h5py

Is there an easy way to **read** `hdf5` file remotely (through ssh) within the Python. As far as I know default `h5py` module does not allow this. What's the easiest way of doing this?

PS. Copying is not an option, I have terabytes of data.

Comment: Are you trying to process them using the Python interpreter on the server or are you attempting to do the processing from your PC? If it's on the server, you can definitely write a script using `h5py` to read the `hdf5` and just execute it via SSH.

Comment: No, I'm using script locally. I want to do all the processing on my laptop, without having to download the `hdf5` files.

Comment: Just mount a remote folder with sshfs or similar.

Answer (score 2):

Not ssh, but h5serv will allow you to read/write hdf5 data over http: [h5serv docs](http://h5serv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/AttrOps/PUT_Attribute.html).  h5pyd is an h5py api compatible package the uses the h5serv REST API: [h5pyd](https://github.com/HDFGroup/h5pyd)